# Using arduino as parallel port

Tags: c#, serial-port, arduino, parallel-port

Guys i and my friend are working on a cnc project. We need parallel ports for this project but all computers we have are laptop. So we don’t have any parallel ports so we decided to use arduino as our parallel port out. I will use c# as linker. I searched the internet but i couldn’t find a virtual parallel port program appropriate to me. I will send commands from my pc to parallel port and from the arduino's digital pins this command will go out. Is there a way to use USB as parallel port with out any converter device

Comment: Old parallel ports required writes in address 378h (data) , 37Ah (control) and reading at the address 379h. Is this parallel port supposed to work with some old software that used those direct addresses?

Comment: Yes we will use old software

Comment: Have you seen stuff like this and looked into virtual software?http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/24831/simulation-of-parallel-port-but-without-a-parallel-port most of your problems these days I believe are in the computer side of the equation. You need to get whatever gets written in LPT and serialize to the virtual com in the arduino.

Comment: http://web.archive.org/web/20140201234850/http://www-user.tu-chemnitz.de/~heha/bastelecke/Rund%20um%20den%20PC/USB2LPT/ul-15.en.htm

Comment: I have seen some stuff like that but those adaptors for printers. Some of the pins are disabled so it is useless for us

Comment: Does this software uses a dll to access the parallel port? In what operating system does it runs? If it uses a dll, you can modify it. Just find which calls it's using. Can you tell which software this is?